# Please make bikes.stackexchange.com redirect to bicycles.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

It can be a bit difficult to tell people how to go to our site, what with the [9 syllable name of "bicycles dot stack exchange dot com"](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-bicycles-stackexchange-com-in-less-than-nine-syllable).  Cutting a couple syllables out so that we can tell people to go to "bikes dot stackexchange dot com" would be really helpful.

So, how about it?  Can we have http://bikes.stackexchange.com redirect to https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/?  Preferably the "smart" way with everything after it so that https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/1234 would redirect to https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/1234

Comment: Interesting: http://s.tk/bikes works, but http://bikes.stackexchange.com doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done:

http://bikes.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sweet! "Bikes" is a lot less awkward to type, too, than "bicycles".